# Improve efficiency of python script containing scipy optimizations

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I am writing a piece of code that runs, but one part is is taking a very long time to complete and ends making the total script execution slow. I am not very advanced in programming so I am not (yet) aware of strategies that would make this run faster.

Here is what the problematicly slow code look like:

```
### forecasting function to be optimized, (example of functions to show the structure of the script)###
def winter_holts_high_low(x):
   pass

def winter_holts_low_high(x):
   pass

def winter_high_low(x):
   pass

def winter_low_high(x):
   pass 

def holts(x):
   pass

def exponential_smoothing(x):
   pass


data2 = data2.set_index('Id')
for i in data2.index:
    x0 = np.array([0.1, 0.1, 0.1])

    solver = data2['solver'].loc[i]

    if data2['seasonality_status'].loc[i] == "seasonal" and data2['trend_status'].loc[i] == "trending" and data2['demand_level'].loc[i] == 'high' and data2['variability'].loc[i] == 'low':
        result = minimize(winter_holts_high_low, x0, bounds=[(0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1)], method=solver)


    if data2['seasonality_status'].loc[i] == "seasonal" and data2['trend_status'].loc[i] == "trending" and (data2['demand_level'].loc[i] == 'low' or data2['variability'].loc[i] == 'high'):
            result = minimize(winter_holts_low_high, x0, bounds=[(0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1)], method=solver)


    if data2['seasonality_status'].loc[i] == "seasonal" and data2['trend_status'].loc[i] == "Not_trending" and data2['demand_level'].loc[i] == 'high' and data2['variability'].loc[i] == 'low':
            result = minimize(winter_high_low, x0, bounds=[(0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1)], method=solver)

    if data2['seasonality_status'].loc[i] == "seasonal" and data2['trend_status'].loc[i] == "Not_trending" and (
            data2['demand_level'].loc[i] == 'low' or data2['variability'].loc[i] == 'high'):
        result = minimize(winter_low_high, x0, bounds=[(0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1)], method=solver)

    if data2['seasonality_status'].loc[i] == "not_seasonal" and data2['trend_status'].loc[i] == "trending":
        result = minimize(holts, x0, bounds=[(0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1)], method=solver)

    if data2['seasonality_status'].loc[i] == "not_seasonal" and data2['trend_status'].loc[i] == "Not_trending":
        result = minimize(exponential_smoothing, x0, bounds=[(0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1)], method=solver)
```

and here is a toy dataset:

```
        deseasonalize_d-1 demand_level variability seasonality_status  \
Id                                                                      
100121         123.031501         high       small       not_seasonal   
100122          74.364646         high       small       not_seasonal   
100131         595.439056         high       small       not_seasonal   
100135         263.901198         high       small       not_seasonal   
100150         179.421932         high       small       not_seasonal   

        trend_status          
Id                                                                     
100121  Not_trending    
100122  Not_trending    
100131  Not_trending  
100135  Not_trending   
100150  Not_trending
```

I know that it is most of the time wiser to use `np.where` instead of if statements, which I have tried as follow:

```
data2 = data2.set_index('Id')
for i in data2.index:
    x0 = np.array([0.1, 0.1, 0.1])


    solver = data2['solver'].loc[i]

    np.where(((data2['seasonality_status'].loc[i] == "seasonal") & (data2['trend_status'].loc[i] == "trending") & (data2['demand_level'].loc[i] == 'high') & (data2['variability'].loc[i] == 'low')),
        minimize(winter_holts_high_low, x0, bounds=[(0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1)], method=solver),"")


    np.where(((data2['seasonality_status'].loc[i] =='seasonal') &(data2['trend_status'].loc[i] == "trending") & ((data2['demand_level'].loc[i] == 'low') | (data2['variability'].loc[i] == 'high'))), minimize(winter_holts_low_high, x0, bounds=[(0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1)], method=solver),"")


    np.where(((data2['seasonality_status'].loc[i] == "seasonal") & (data2['trend_status'].loc[i] == "Not_trending") & ( data2['demand_level'].loc[i] == 'high') & (data2['variability'].loc[i] == 'low')), minimize(winter_high_low, x0, bounds=[(0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1)], method=solver), "")

    np.where(((data2['seasonality_status'].loc[i] == 'seasonal') & (data2['trend_status'].loc[i] == "Not_trending") & ((data2['demand_level'].loc[i] == 'low') | (data2['variability'].loc[i] == 'high'))), minimize(winter_low_high, x0, bounds=[(0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1)], method=solver), "")
```

I am not sure what is going on but the script takes `1 minute and 09 secondes` to complete with if statements and more than `5 minutes` with `np.where`. I curious to see how this could be optimized to run faster.

Comment: No, that's not how use `where` to save time. You still have `data2.index` loop. You are doing all `minimize` with the `where`, as opposed to sekected ones with `if`.

Comment: `np.where` can be used to select between two columns of values, based on matching boolean column.  In that sense it can replace iteration and an `if` test.   But its arguments are evaluated in full before being passed to `where`.  Study simpler applications to dataframes before investing more time trying to get this to work.  The `minimize` calculations are expensive, so perform them wisely.